# Need to use the browser's back button to redirect to the home page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a static HTML demo that emulates the behavior of a web portal that logs you out when you press the back button.

How might one do this using javascript? Is it possible?

Comment: Although I don't like this approach, I like the question because 1) I'm interested to know if it's possible and 2) I want future searches on the subject to see the "it's bad form" answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is generally considered bad form to override the behavior of the Back button.

Comment: This is a common customer requirement, though.

Comment: Agreed. It seems rude and also confusing to thwart the user's expecations of what the back button does. Why not have a "logout" button?

Comment: I know.. it pains me to aim to do this, but it's for a usability test to hopefully prove that this function needs to be changed in the actual system!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to send a value between pages.  For the demo, the logout page could set a "LoggedOut=1" cookie.  Then in the top of all of your site's pages, have javascript that checks for the cookie.  If set, redirect the user to the home page.  The trick is that you have to use javascript to handle the redirect since the script has to already be in the user's browser cache.

Note that this doesn't add any security to the app.  It just adds a layer of obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hack with `iframe` element to hijack previous entry in the browser history, so single click of *back* button will return to 'not logged in' state. GMail uses that heavily, thats why they still have 'basic HTML' webmail UI.